# passing data from page to another using webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have searched for a while trying to figure something out but I could not actually slove it , I am new to web development and I am using webpack which is a bit complicated. All I want to is passing my data from booking.html to booking-step.html using the same index.js.

and here is my webpack configuration

```
module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js'
},
devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
},
plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'index.html',
        template: './src/js/view/booking.html',
        chunks:[]
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        filename: 'booking-step2.html',
        template: './src/js/view/booking-step2.html',
        chunks:[]
    }),
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: "bundle.css"
    })
],

module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader'
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/,
            use: [
                {
                    // After all CSS loaders we use plugin to do his work.
                    // It gets all transformed CSS and extracts it into separate
                    // single bundled file
                    loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader
                },
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader'
                },
            ]
        },
        {
            test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
            use: [
                {

                    loader: "file-loader",

                    // In options we can set different things like format
                    // and directory to save
                    options: {
                        outputPath: 'images'
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

and here is my index.js file
[image: index code]

Comment: What do you mean by “passing my data”?

Comment: `window.location.href =  " ... "` reloads the page. You need to either persist your info to something like local storage or pass it through as a query parameter.

Comment: Like the user  enter his booking details in the first page such as name and passport number and when he clicks next, the data goes to the second page

Comment: @DigitalDrifter and then where i can get it back while I am using only one js file , like if i send it from the index.js i can still load the second HTML within the same index.js

Comment: This doesn’t sound like a job for webpack. If you need to persist it across page loads you might look at the [web storage api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) (session storage specifically), or build it as a single page app. For long term persistence you’ll need something on the server side.

Comment: Another option would be to use a query string in the url to pass the data on to the second page. You could do that with a form action (easier) or by appending it to your redirect programmatically (slightly harder, but not a big deal).

Comment: Thanks, will check on that